# Data type changed to TEXT and NUM after table joining using SQLite

Tags: sqlite

There are some tables which have columns with the data types "varchar", "decimal" and "datetime" in .db file of SQLite. After joining these tables, the columns become "Text" and "NUM", even the datetime fields have become "NUM" data type.

Is there a way to prevent the data types change when joining tables?
Is there a way to change the data types "Text" and "NUM" back to normal, like using SQLite commands?

[image: The data type list of columns of the joined table]

Comment: There are no  "varchar", "decimal" and "datetime" data types in SQLite. Read this: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: There is no NUM data type either, but somehow the NUM data type shows after table joining. And actually I can change the data field to "varchar", "decimal" and "datetime" in SQLite.

Comment: NUM stands for NUMERIC. You can change the data type to anything like VARCHAR but the actual data type will be TEXT.